# If $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ has three distinct integral roots and $f(x^2+2x+2)$ has no real roots, then...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Suppose that $f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ has three distinct integral roots and $f(x^2+2x+2)$ has no real roots.
>
> 1. What is the minimum value of $a$?
> 2. What is the minimum value of $b$?
> 3. What is the minimum value of $c$?
> 4. In the case when $a$, $b$ and $c$ take their minimum values, if the roots of $f'(x) = K$ are equal, then what is $K$?

**My attempt:**

I factorised $g(x) = x^2+2x+2$ as $(x+1)^2 + 1$. For all values of $g(x)$, $f(x)$ will always give a non-zero value. I tried getting multiple linear equations in $a$, $b$ and, $c$, but it got me nowhere. I don't see any other way to obtain minimum values of said variables, let alone attempt question 4.

This is a problem from a revision worksheet for our polynomials class.

Currently, I have no other ideas as to how to approach solving this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: $f(x^2+2x+2) = 0$ if and only if $x^2+2x+2$ equals one of the roots of $f(y) = 0$, but all these are integers. Thus, you want a list of integer values of $y$ such that $x^2+2x+2 = y$ has nonreal roots (which is easily found by checking the sign of the discriminant). Once you have all those integer values of $y$, then only those values can be roots of $f$. Finding all such $y$ is then a starting point for your question. Then, you use Vieta's formulas to relate the values of $a,b,c$ to these roots. That answers the first three parts of the question.

Comment: Hint: What are all the possible values of $x^2+2x+2$, if $x$ can be any real number?

Answer (score 1):

$f(y) = 0$ has three distinct integral solutions for $y$

Thus, for $f(x^2 + 2x + 2)$ to not have integral solutions : 
$x^2 + 2x + 2 = y$ cannot have any real solutions. Checking the sign of discriminant we get 
$y = [0, -1, -2 ...]$ which is essentially [ $y  < 1$ ]

This implies that for minimum values of coefficients; $a$, $b$, and $c$. We use Vieta Relations and get the answers to the questions as : 
$a = 3$ 
$b = 2$ 
$c = 0$ 
$k = -1$

Credits to Sarvesh and aschepler for their much needed help.

Comment: Hey, good to know you could finish it off.

Comment: Oh yes, Writing the answer here took some time but I was able to piece it all together as soon as you commented. Quite neat:) Opened up another way to think about problems as such, Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your factorization shows that $g$ is surjective from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[1,+\infty[$. Therefore, $f(g(x))$ has no real root is equivalent to all the roots of $f$ are $< 1$ thus $\leqslant 0$ because they are integral. Let $r_1,r_2,r_3$ be the roots of $f$. Newton relations give you,
$$
r_1 + r_2 + r_3 = -a, \qquad r_1r_2 + r_2r_3 + r_3r_1 = b, \qquad r_1r_2r_3 = -c.
$$
Knowing that for all $i$, $r_i \leqslant 0$, you can deduce bounds on $a,b,c$, like for example $a = -r_1 - r_2 - r_3 \geqslant 0$. As the $r_i$ are distinct you even have $a \geqslant 0 + 1 + 2 = 3$. Try to do the same for $b$ and $c$ to decue bounds $a_0$, $b_0$ and $c_0$. Verify that those bounds are optimal by checking that $x^3 + a_0x^2 + b_0x + c_0$ indeed have three disctinct integral non-positive roots, and question $4$ is easy by computing the discriminant of $f' - K$.

Comment: Figured it out pretty quick. Thanks anyway!